# How to export specific table from Oracle db in csv using terminal?

Tags: oracle

I'm using SQL Developer tool, but the data size is big and it takes a long time, so I'm thinking about exporting data in csv format from the terminal. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll take a lot of time anyway. "Terminal" (if you mean "SQL*Plus" by saying that) won't be any faster, as you'd spool the result into a file.

Try with a PL/SQL procedure which utilizes UTL_FILE and creates the output. It'll reside on the database server, which might be a drawback if you don't have access to it so - talk to your DBA to

- create a directory (Oracle object which points to directory on a server)
- grant READ and WRITE privileges to Oracle user which will create that output file

Then, write a procedure and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your solution